# How to determine what a cluster is about?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have tweets retrieved using the Twitter API and need to group the tweets into 2 categories. To do the grouping I used doc2vec to represent the tweets into numerical form and then performed DBSCAN algorithm clustering. However, how do I know what category a cluster belongs to? My output is just tweets assigned to different clusters.

For example, I need to know which tweet indicates **the needs of the people** and which tweets indicate that **people have help to offer**.

How can I make out which cluster has what type of tweets?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably neither cluster is a either of these two things.

Clustering is unsupervised. You don't get to control what it finds. It could be tweets that contain the f... word vs. tweets that don't.

If you want something specific such as "needs" and "offers", then you absolutely *need* to train a supervised algorithm from labeled data.

Comment: Thank you!...but in general, if I am clustering documents, and like you said I can't control what it finds... how do I know **what** my cluster found? Do I need to manually analyze the clusters to figure that out? ...I am very new to this so please forgive me if its a stupid doubt to ask..

Comment: Yes. You'll need to analyze the cluster, by looking at the actual data and summary statistics, for example. Or at differences between clusters.